# How to do Silent installation without UAC or App Is running as admin?

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, silent-installer

I want to do Silent installation. I know the command which do that "msiexec.exe /qn", but i can't do that if my application isn't running as administrator.
note:- my msi installer is created using WIX Toolset

```
Process process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                FileName = @"msiexec.exe",
                Arguments = string.Format(@"/i ""E:\Build 16\ColiboConnect.msi"" /qn"),
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                CreateNoWindow = false
            }
        };
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: If this was possible wouldn't you think many bad guys would exploit this?

Comment: startInfo.Verb = "runas";

Comment: you need UseShellExecute = true as well for the "runas" verb to work. I would also consider sending "/l*v logpath\logfile.txt" to to msiexec's cmd line so you can get a log file somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved our problem using Windows Service. Our app will download the new msi, then call a WCF service, passing the path of the installer and the Service will install the new version without any problems because our service run under local account system and i think this is the only supported solution

Answer (score 1):

You are requesting silent MSI installation therefore MSI will not display any UI - nor the UAC dialog.

Your parent process must already run with elevated privileges, or you must request elevation from Windows and use the privileges token to run new process.